# How to relate geofence with the database in my android device?

Tags: android, database, android-geofence

I am pretty new to the android app development and I would like to develop an app about geofencing. Under my understanding, geofencing can be related to my own database stored in the device memory and it has a limitation that only 100 geofencing can be used at the same time. (Actually I am not sure if my understanding is right. If it is not, please correct me.)

My question is: Can I store several lists of geofences in my device and only enable the list which I want using the app? so, I can have more than 100 geofences but use less than 100 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Yes, you can.** I'm not sure what the exact space requirements would be but I don't see a problem in saving several lists of 100 entries each.

For more information on how to save data in Android I'd recommend looking at [this training module](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html). You don't *have* to save the data - you could just keep it in working memory and redownload the lists every time. Maybe that would make more sense in your case, I don't know.